# generating a sequence of values with differents formats and lengh of rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to find documentno missing from a sequence of values from table with differents formats and length. For example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0d3a6a647c6ef2a9063c7f3289446998

I want to find the missing documentno like : `'AGB/2021/2051','AGB/2021/2052','AGB/2021/2053','AGB/2021/2054', PROFS / 2021 / 02051_P, PROFS / 2021 / 02052_P, PROFS / 2021 / 02053_P, PROFS / 2021 / 02054_P ,'BABA/2021/02057', 'BABA/ 2021/02058', 'BABA / 2021/02059, and 'MAMAMA/2021/0206011','MAMAMA/2021/0206012','MAMAMA/2021/0206013'`

```
CREATE TABLE c_order (
  "order_id" VARCHAR(22),
  "documentno" VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO c_order
  ("order_id", "documentno")
VALUES
  ('100001119', 'AGB/2021/2050'),
  ('100001124' ,'AGB/2021/2055'),
  ('100001126' ,'PROFS/2021/02060'),
  ('100001129' ,'PROFS/2021/02065'),
  ('100001120', 'BABA/2020/02056_p'),
  ('100001127' ,'BABA/2020/02060_p'),
  ('100001118' ,'MAMAMA/2021/0206010'),
  ('100001122' ,'MAMAMA/2021/0206014')
```

Query used

```
with cte as (
  select left(documentno,13) lpart, 
         regexp_replace(split_part(documentno, '/', 3), '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int as num
  from c_order
), minmax as (
  select lpart, min(num) minpart, max(num) maxpart
  from cte
  group by lpart
)
select lpart||t.doc_no as missing_doc_no
from minmax m
  cross join generate_series(minpart, maxpart) as t(doc_no) 
  where not exists (select * 
                  from c_order c
                  where regexp_replace(split_part(c.documentno, '/', 3), '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int = t.doc_no)
```

This query generates a documentno but not in good format for all rows considering lengh of each row.

I want a query that work for all missing documentno.

Comment: You are aware that lines 11 and 15 of your fiddle are identical?

Comment: What's wrong with the answers [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=202253b411acfa0776a7d995bcfbcd5d) - see end?